# Linux Mint 15 WiFi hotspot options

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, networkmanager

I'm trying to configure a hotspot in my Linux Mint 15. There are no specific manuals for 15, but I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyJpFKdzH30) which describes hot to make a hotspot in Mint 14.

Creating it in Mint 15 not much differ, but I cannot find a button to configure hotspot. Here is how my Network Manager looks like when hotspot is on:

[image]

I cannot find `Options` button. Hot can I configure SSID, security type and key without it?

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of removing features and make it impossible to get things done.

Comment: Edit /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf and add your encryption type and password. use [this link](http://machineawakening.blogspot.nl/2013/07/setup-wireless-access-point-with-mint.html) as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used Mint 15 myself, but, you can right click on the Network Manager icon in your panel and select Edit Connections.

[image: Network Connections]

You will see a option 'Hotspot' under the Wi-Fi section. Edit that and you can set the SSID, the type of security(WEP/ WPA2) and the key.

[image: Hotspot settings]